# How do I check if an array of Booleans is all true in Actionscript 3?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, boolean

Well, technically not all the Booleans. I have an array (ArrayMain) that stores a player and a bunch of other movieclips in an array, and I have another array of Booleans (this corresponds to the ArrayMain and is called ArrayDeadCheck) that I need to check.

My player is the first in the array, so it occupies ArrayMain[0] and in ArrayDeadCheck will always be false (it never dies). I need to loop through the rest of ArrayDeadCheck (which can vary because for my enemy number from level to level can change, so ArrayMain's length might vary). So I need to do something like this?:

```
for (var i:int=1; i < ArrayMain.length; i++)
{ 
    //Code/condition?? that does this: 
    //if all of the Booleans in ArrayMain from 1 to n are true

    if (Insert condition here)

    {

    //trigger another Boolean called EndGame to end the game

    EndGame = true;

    }
}
```

Sorry if this is a repeated question (I saw a similar question but that was in Java, AS3 conversion please?) or if it's formatted weirdly, it's my first question here. Please help!! And thank you very much in advance, if anyone is kind enough to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if all you have to do is to check if there is `false` in the array you can use `indexOf` function in the form:

```
if(ArrayMain.indexOf(false) == -1)
{
    //all true
}
else 
{
    //there is at least on false values
}
```

that's all:)

p.s. ArrayMain is poor choice for a name of a variable, it fits Class name

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will check if it works with the code later. Always good to know how to do things in... multiple ways. :)
Oh, and yeah, ArrayMain is just a temp name, but thank you!

Comment: This is the proper way to do it(faster I'm sure). I don't code in ActionScript and didn't know this functionality was available. Then again, I only looked up a few things.

Answer (score 0):

```
var alive:bool = true;
for (var i:int=1; i < ArrayMain.length; i++)
{ 
  if ( ArrayDeadCheck[i] )
     continue; // the loop will skip over the rest of the code to the next position

   alive = false;
   break; // stops the loop
}
if (alive) // this means all elements in the array were true.
   // do whatever is needed.
```

Basically this code just makes a variable at the begging(`alive`) a boolean to be checked at the end of the loop. 
All of your array elements will be checked and as soon as one of them is not true, the array is broken.

-- you may need to fix the code a little bit. I've never coded in Acgtionscript before.

[Go to this site](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/loops.html), and scroll down to "break and continue"

Comment: Sigh, sorry, I still don't get it. I can't seem to get it to work in my script either, perhaps I'm just using "continue" incorrectly (first time i've had to use it in my scripts). Can anyone help please?

Comment: Edit: It works, but my knowledge of how continue works is still shaky, that's all. Thank you very much for your help in any case!

Comment: I added a site that will help you understand loops a bit more. But mostly to give you an idea of how the `continue` statement works. For a brief idea of what it is, `continue` just skips the rest of the code to be executed on to the next part of the loop. By the way, could you accept my answer since it was a fix. If you need me to explain in further detail on my answer just ask.